# Jquery based notification repeats itself

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using following CSS and HTML code to display a notification, when an event occurs.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="notification_wrapper">
            <div id="notification"></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#notification_wrapper 
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1060;
}

#notification 
{
    left: -50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#notification").text("A message tobe displayed").fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
```

Now the problem,

When I execute above jQuery code with a button click, notification displays fine and fades out with 5 seconds.
But if I click that button again within those 5 seconds, second notification lines up in queue and it again displays notification after first one fades out after 5 seconds.

I want it to be running this way.
When I press a button, notification should display for 5 seconds. If I again press that button within 5 seconds, first one should completely disappear and new one should appear.

**I am attaching a FIDDLE for demo.
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltm20jc0/1/)**

Comment: can you add a jfiddle for it !!!

Comment: I already did.Its at the end of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `.stop(true, true)` at the beginning of your chain to stop the currently running animation.

```
$("#notification").text("A message to display").stop(true, true).fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ltm20jc0/5/

> http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you @connexo.

Answer (score 2):

You need check if animation is running:

```
var is_anim = false;
$(":button").click(function(){
    if(is_anim) return;
    is_anim = true;
    $("#notification").text("A message to display").fadeIn().fadeOut(5000, function(){
       is_anim = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: No this is not what I wanted.This will wait for first message to fade away and then it will show second one. I want second message to be displayed fresh when first message is showing and within those 5 seconds of fade out, user presses button again. When button is again pressed, first one should completely removed and new one should be displayed

Comment: @Yvette No, this does not answer the question. I clearly told what i wanted in my original question. So this is not the answer.

Comment: @Yvette I havent changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work for you with the jquery `.stop()` https://api.jquery.com/stop/, as in this: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/awwwpn17/2/)

```js
var counter = 1;
$(":button").click(function() {
  $("#notification").text('Message: ' + counter + ' to display').stop().fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
  counter++;
});
```

```css
#notification_wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1060;
}
#notification {
  left: -50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification_wrapper">
  <div id="notification"></div>
</div>
<input type=button value=click />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do

```
$(":button").click(function(){
$("#notification").stop();    
$("#notification").text("A message to display").fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

I have also updated your fiddle with the new code

Comment: Yes I did changed it.

Comment: I liked @connexo 's answer useful.

Comment: @Yvette not an issue ... :)

Comment: you can make use of the chaining functions ability in jQuery and just add the .stop() right before .text(), this will make it one line and won't query the `#notification` twice; http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp

Comment: @LalitMehra I havent marked any correct answers as NOT USEFUL.

Comment: @Hemal ... It's been sorted out .. Yvette did mistakenly